# Designing for mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I'm trying to adapt my website for mobiles and by now I'm quite disoriented.

I've got 2 test pages, t3.html and t4.html.

The first one (t3) without header and footer seems to fit ok to screen width in real iPhone and HTC, but not on my Opera Mobile Emulator for Samsung Galaxy or HTC nor on my iPhone (¿3?) emulator.

The second one (t4) with header and footer (which is what I really want to have) makes a big wide for header and footer and keeps a narrow form and tiny fonts for the main content, this happens in real iPhone, HTC and in my Opera Mobile Emulator, not in my Iphone (¿3?) emulator.

The thing is, if I didn't forget any, there aren't any width properties set (except for the form inputs and labels, which are near 200px width) so all divs should span to device's screen width, or that's what I think.

The examples are:
http://s380890671.mialojamiento.es/mobile/t3.html
http://s380890671.mialojamiento.es/mobile/t4.html

My goal is that everthing fits the mobile screen width. Can you help me or point me to a good and up-to-date mobile designing article? The ones I found are a few years old.

Thank you

Comment: why don't you try jquerymobile(http://www.jquerymobile.com)?

Comment: What for? what I read about it is taht it is a subset of jQuery, but I didn't read anythign about design

Comment: Just go to the site and view the examples,you will build the site using it with any scripting language like PHP. Also view this http://jquerymobile.com/resources/

Comment: Well, it seems to work, but the thing is it uses it's own jquery css and I am in a very advanced stage of the design so I would prefer an indication on how to fix my own design, anyway I'll keep playing with it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Smashing Magazine has a great resource on many aspects of mobile web development.

The overview features hand-picked and organized selections on the most useful and popular of Smashing Magazine’s articles related to design and development for mobile devices:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/guidelines-for-mobile-web-development